# Why my MacBook pro is not booting and giving electric shock when touched

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, charging, power

My Mac book pro's not booting up since last two days and I'm getting electric shock whenever I touch the Mac book pro provided Mac book is plugged with socket.

I tried plugging in to different sockets but I'm still getting the electric shock.

Any ideas on what could be the potential problem

[image]

Please find the current that passes through the laptop

Update:

[image]

The thing is in some places of laptop , the current is not passing but in other places it's passing.

Now the laptop is not even showing the battery dead symbol in the above screen.

Comment: If you get an electric shock there's clearly some hardware defect. Do not plug it in any more and bring it to Apple for repair (or an authorized dealer).

Comment: If you're getting a true shock & not just a 'tingly buzz' then suspect the charger. If you have another, try that. If not, then Apple Store. Note that a true shock could also kill the computer as well as you, so don't experiment if you're uncertain.

Comment: (Seems like it is indeed a potential problem ;) )

Comment: The shock is not deadly but it certainly makes you get your hand off of it.

Comment: @DarkDust - Nearest authorised dealer is far away , I'm thinking if there's any DIY troubleshoot that I can try and save my time

Comment: Buy a new power supply, assuming you've already tested your mains supply.

Comment: If you still have warranty on your device, you should contact your dealer. Maybe a solution via parcel service can be arranged. If you want to go the DIY route: a new power supply as Tetsujin suggests is really a good start, but if that doesn't solve the problem it might be a wiring issue inside the device and then you should really consult someone who has experience with repairing electronic devices.

Comment: @DarkDust - This makes sense to me.

Comment: @DarkDust please find my update in the post